# How to overload and bind argument types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a function `addEventListener`

This function has two arguments, the `event` and the `listener`.

I have some specific events: ex. `onScroll`, `onClick`, `onDoubleClick`.

Depending on the `event` I want to have a separate signature / type for the `listener` argument.

So if I start typing:

```
addEventListener('onClick', (param: OnClickType) => // here I want to resolve a certain listener type )

// or

addEventListener('onScroll', (param: OnScrollType) => // here I want to resolve a certain listener type )
```

Is this possible in typescript ?

[EDIT]

Something like this:

[image]

[EDIT2]

```
export type OnClick = (event: 'onclick', listener: (x: number) => void) => void
export type OnScroll = (event: 'onscroll', listener: (x: string) => void) => void

export type EventListener = OnClick | OnScroll;

const addEventListener: EventListener = (ev, ls) => {
    console.log(ev, ls);
    return;
}

addEventListener('onclick', )
```

What I want is to infer the type of the second argument of the function (`listener`) depending on the value of the first argument (`event`).

Comment: Yes, just use overloads

Comment: @AlekseyL. It does not seem clear to me, because it does not have to do with the parameters itself but with their values instead, I mean the value of the event decides the type of the listener which I have no idea how to do

Comment: look at interfaces https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NVgvGm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqQVdm) work for you?  You want an `EventListener` to act like *both* an `OnClick` *and* an `OnScroll`, so you need an intersection (`&`) instead of a union (`|`).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please [edit] the code example to show your unsatisfied use case(s).

Comment: @jcalz But please if it's possible to write it more elegantly, something like storing the event names in a dictionary and infering the listener type ??

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2ELjW)?  I can write that up as an answer if you can verify that it meets your needs.

Comment: @jcalz Thats perfect! Thank you. If you want you can answer the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just a few hardcoded function types like `OnClick` and `OnScroll`:

```
type OnClick = (event: 'onclick', listener: (x: number) => void) => void
type OnScroll = (event: 'onscroll', listener: (x: string) => void) => void
```

and you want to say that an `EventListener` can behave like all of them, you can manually rewrite both call signatures into a single, [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function type:

```
type EventListener = {
    (event: 'onclick', listener: (x: number) => void): void;
    (event: 'onscroll', listener: (x: string) => void): void;
}

const addEventListener: EventListener = (ev, ls) => {
    console.log(ev, ls);
    return;
}

addEventListener('onclick', x => console.log(x.toFixed(2))); // okay
addEventListener('onscroll', x => console.log(x.toUpperCase())); // okay
```

---

Equivalently, you can just write `EventListener` as [the intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the existing function types:

```
type EventListener = OnClick & OnScroll;
```

This puts both call signatures into the same type, as an overloaded function type with the `OnClick` signature first and the `OnScroll` signature second.  So when you call an `EventListener` the compiler will try to resolve the `OnClick` call signature first, and then fall back to `OnScroll` if that fails.  Since `"onclick"` and `"onscroll"` are mutually exclusives, the order doesn't really matter here.  But there are cases where order of call signature resolution does matter, and then a type `F1 & F2` will behave differently from `F2 & F1` (which might be surprising since intersections are conceptually unordered).

---

If you have a bunch of different event names and payload types and you don't want to manually write out one call signature for each such pair, you can forgo multi-call signature overloads in favor of a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function:

```
interface EventMap {
    onclick: number;
    onscroll: string;
}

type EventListener = <E extends keyof EventMap>(
    event: E, listener: (x: EventMap[E]) => void
) => void;
```

This behaves similarly (the prior implementation of and calls to `addEventListener()` still work), but now you can just add a new line to `EventMap` for each new event name / payload type pair.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCB3ATgSwC64mAHkA3CTAGwHsQATKJAbwFgAoNpTpXATxmQCiZYLgAy2KAWDkkAXiYcuSgBQRhuAFxIA5FWDwK2eAGttAGiSHJhcluUAPLcACuYAEbkAlHIB8SElTYtJ5aAUEA3IpKnKrqWrrAUPCYVBQU5pYSUrZIDlqSOMAA5t6yfmHBoYG0kaxKAL5sUUjwepJIdLRChGJZNpha3SLi1tKYcrlqFhRQpX4sddGcrYmpEAB01EWx07O1S5yYELjOmMD7XI3si5ydQ72j5MoJBkamFva+LW1rm1Tb9nWuCoADFsPYILRlAAmTxwi63WhddQjbKYZ5tZKpdIfL4rKC-LYOIFUACqMH4mAAwiAoBBlHDPLUrk1WKBILAEMgABIgTC0Vq0SGkcjUOgMBZKXj8JBEYBUwwmCaxHrxPSvEwZKxouyOJAudxeL4VOb+arNaXIOUAZSxaWValVOkxKTSWr6Y11+VwhRKxuqpoqrKlfEEKI9MnkcoVbyQADJZcBba6KLVmvjcB0kfdUf1BuHHuN5DtLLMvpKDvjCf8SzMmc0lEcTmcEUgWTcs8iermxhj9Ir3khPmVvqsKBsiYDgWCIVDYfDmncC2i+0kUxlh34q+O-gCSeTKTS6QyF6x2+zoHBEEgAOL9IyiKhUYzOGAKa5KbAicgAMy5SHuABZEA3wrJZ1QHJxXA8TBWyUF1sW9X1WyuEMZRzCMiyQAAeAQkAgewpHoJBjAgHgqB-AD1GAmAfGUBsuEdERBmmTCvSonoaIAbQEABdQNzQ7ASImDLgM07DDC3zbtMIdEhdlNMDom3CcaymUt6w7RtjlOc5mnbRds2Xfo+w1QdN1HAkd0nEkZ0hGFGVbJcZMLVc7RxIc8R+ayaynMkKXII96Ucth2yAA)